# SPARQL Query For Getting Individual in Protege 5.0

Tags: sparql

I have an ontology for Child.

I have a class `User` and `Mobile` and I have an ObjectProperty `HasMobile` and DataProperty `HasAge` (integer) with individuals as `Samsung`, `nokia` and `Iphone`.

What will be the Sparql Query if I ask: Tell me the Individual which has a `Samsung` phone or which has age 20?

I have tried the following Sparql query, but it does not work.

```
SELECT   ?individual   ?HasMobile
    WHERE { ?individual  User:HasMobile "Nokia".}
```

Comment: Sorry, but look at your query...where is the variable `?HasMobile` bound? Nowhere, correct. Next, is `User` the correct prefix which is defined in the query by `PREFIX User: <> `? Moreover, `HasMobile` is an object property, thus, the values are individuals and **not** string literals like `"Nokia"`. Obviously, you have to use the URI of Nokia (resp. Samsung). Finally, `FILTER` is your friend. Clearly, on the object variable of the triple pattern which retrieves the age, i.e. you need something like `?individual User:HasAge ?age . FILTER(...)` To be honest an RDF/SPARQL tutorial helps

Comment: @AKSW Query Executes but no output means prefix is right and Syntax aswell. ?HasMobile is a oject property  User is class which has Child has an individual and i have another class which has Nokia as an individual . 
I want to get the result from my query when i ask which Individual has  Nokia. I am Stuck. Kindly do me a favour.

Comment: The variable `?HasMobile` is **not** an object property! It is a variable which is nowhere bound in the WHERE part of your query. And as I told you, "Nokia" is an RDF literal, not an individual which is denotes by an URI in your data. Do you understand this or not?

Comment: i am Sorry but i cant understand

Comment: That's a problem. Please have a look at the RDF data model documentation, you should understand what an RDF triple is made of because SPARQL is the query language for RDF. If you don't know the difference between a URI and a literal, well - you're lost with SPARQL. `<http:example.org/a>, ex:a, "abc", "20"^^xsd:integer, ?s `